# Cannot find symbol 'floor' at runtime

Tags: android, android-ndk, cross-platform, libm

I cross-compiled the http Mongoose server for Android using Linux as BUILD system, android-ndk from Google as toolchain and a custom script that finally executes next command:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon \
  -mfloat-abi=softfp -mvectorize-with-neon-quad \
  -I /opt/android-ndk-r9d/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include \
  -I ~/Package_sources/BUILD_arm-linux-androideabi/include \
  -DMONGOOSE_USE_LUA -DMONGOOSE_USE_LUA_SQLITE3 \ 
  -L/opt/android-ndk-r9d/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib \
  -L~/Package_sources/BUILD_arm-linux-androideabi/lib \
  -L~/Package_sources/BUILD_arm-linux-androideabi/lib -lluasqlite3 \
  server.c mongoose.c -o server -llua51 -lm
```

The scripts works fine with no errors and a final 'server' elf executable is created. The problem I have now is when trying to launch it on Android. It complains that math symbols (defined in libm) like "floor" can not be found. **I don't really understand why they can be found at compile time but not at run time**, but I have some doubts about cross-compiling for Android and compilation setup that I describe next:

- Some options/flags I chose to cross-compile are arbitrary since I do not fully understand all the (thousands of) gcc options and I chose what people suggest on different forums. In particular the -mfloat-abi=softfp, -mfpu=neon and -mvectorize-with-neon-quad
- I also chose arbitrarily the platforms/android-19 since it was the newest installed in my system. I don't know exactly how different android-"N" versions differs and what are the implications of choosing one or another (is it safer to choose the newest one?, the oldest one?, or must I choose a different one for each different device/target?).
- I also chose arbitrarily the gcc-4.6 arm-linux-androideabi-gcc build. There is also a gcc-4.8 installed in the android-ndk. Is there any preference, or again it depends on the final target? (or maybe it has nothing to do)

Thanks in advance for any help, hint or link!

Comment: `nm -D /opt/android-ndk-r9d/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/libm.so | grep floor` shows that **floor()** is defined there. Can you add `-v` flag to get verbose information about the actual link command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it looks the source of problems was a missing compilation flag in the LUA libraries (-DLUA_USE_DLOPEN). This caused the software to compile properly, but at runtime it failed to load so symbols defined "anywhere else".